# key value pair in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to execute a mapper only job using hadoop-streaming.
Basically I have a csv input file with 6 fields and the 6th field is salary. I would like to sort the file on salary in descending order. It works perfectly fine with the shell script "task1.1_map.sh"(tr -d '$' | sort -t, -n -r -k6)

Input file:

```
DPT     ,NAME    ,ADDRESS ,TTL #   ,PC      ,SAL-RATE  
868,B J  SANDIFORD,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,12702,X,$5.00  
868,C A  WIGFALL,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,12702,X,$5.00  
69,A E A-AWOSOGBA,HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S,52311,A,$51955.00  
868,K D AABY,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,10209,X,$12.00  
56,I D AADIL,POLICE DEPARTMENT,71012,A,$46953.00  
69,M   AAKIRI,HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S,56056,A,$33000.00  
464,A   AALAI,CUNY QUEENSBOROUGH COMMUNI,4607,N,$73.53  
998,A V AALEVIK,N.Y.C. TRANSIT AUTHORITY,402,2,$33280.00  
998,M   AAMIR,N.Y.C. TRANSIT AUTHORITY,00T07,4,$60878.00
```

Output File:

```
notroot@ubuntu:~/lab/hdfs/datan1/current/subdir60$ hadoop fs -cat /output/Task1.3/part-00000
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

464,A   AALAI,CUNY QUEENSBOROUGH COMMUNI,4607,N,73.53  
56,I D AADIL,POLICE DEPARTMENT,71012,A,46953.00  
69,A E A-AWOSOGBA,HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S,52311,A,51955.00  
69,M   AAKIRI,HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S,56056,A,33000.00  
868,B J  SANDIFORD,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,12702,X,5.00  
868,C A  WIGFALL,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,12702,X,5.00  
868,K D AABY,DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM,10209,X,12.00  
998,A V AALEVIK,N.Y.C. TRANSIT AUTHORITY,402,2,33280.00  
998,M   AAMIR,N.Y.C. TRANSIT AUTHORITY,00T07,4,60878.00  
DPT     ,NAME    ,ADDRESS ,TTL #   ,PC      ,SAL-RATE
```

Why does it does not sort in mapper when I do using the following command?

```
hadoop jar /home/notroot/lab/software/hadoop-1.0.3/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar \  
-D stream.map.input.field.separator=, \  
-input /input/Civil_List_2016.csv -output /output/Task1.3 \  
-mapper /home/notroot/lab/data/mapreduce_data_examples/jpmc_exercise/task1.1_map.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Ambrish for indenting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600495/hadoop-streaming-mapper-byte-offset-not-being-generated?rq=1

Comment: How are we supposed to help without your mapper code?

Comment: My mapper code is mentioned above, it is just 1 line shell (tr -d '$' | sort -t, -n -r -k6). I have placed this command in the script  "task1.1_map.sh"